# Dual boot w/ Windows 10 Technical Prebuild

Tags: dual-boot

when I installed the Windows 10 Technical, it rewrote my BIOS to default boot to Windows. I used to have the boot options on startup. Now I have to hit ESC and go through a menu, select "Ubuntu Boot", then it gives the boot options. Is there a way to fix this? Also, is there a way to have it start right at Ubuntu unless I hit ESC and go into the list? Sorry if this is sounding confusing. I guess I'd just like the default to be Ubuntu. How do I fix that much? Thanks.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? And What brand/model system?

Answer (score 0):

Just boot into Ubuntu, open Terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and run the commands:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

I suppose Windows AND Ubuntu are installed in your "first HD", but you have more than one make sure in which one the SOs are installed in (for example, if they are installed in 'HD 2', use /dev/sdb. Please note the difference between HD and partition).

Then run `sudo update-grub`
.

Answer (score 0):

I went through and just verified my boot sequence making the UEFI the primary boot. It then just goes right to the option of Elementary, safe mode, Windows, etc. That way, starting the computer, if i do nothing, automatically jumps right into Elementary. Worked for me, anyway.